# Triangular mesh in python

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I have points in a plane. I want each point to be a vertex of at least one triangle. I also want to fill the plane confined within the vertices with no overlapping triangles. Something like:

[image]

Note that for each pair of points in any triangle, the line connecting them consists of points that are also in some triangle.

I want to get the list of all vertices triplets from which a triangle can be defined. In the picture, there would be 6 such triplets.

My attempt is this one:

```
indices = range(locs.shape[0])
visited = []
ind_list = []
for ind in indices:
    if ind not in visited:
        visited.append(ind)
        nearest_idx = np.argsort(distances[ind])[1:3]
        for ni in nearest_idx:
            visited.append(ni)
        ind_list.append([ind]+list(nearest_idx))
```

where `locs` is a Nx2 array containing the (x,y) coordinates of each vertex, `distances` is a NxN matrix whose i,j component is the euclidean distance between the i-th vertex and the j-th vertex. Note that `ind_list` is a list of indices that allow me to get the vertices by `locs[ind_list]`. What I want is the correct `ind_list`. In my case I clearly omit some of the triplets. An example of this failure can be seen in this figure:

[image]

where there are blank regions. Instead I want all the space to be filled with no overlapping triangles. Any idea of how to achieve this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is not a trivial problem... from the shape of your mesh, you do not seem to want an arbitrary triangulation. Maybe you want to look into `scipy voronoi`, or `scipy delaunay triangulation`.Graphics libraries may have triangular mesh generation too, but idk which one to point you to. Maybe matplotlib has that too, idk.

Comment: See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/spatial.html

Comment: Thanks for the great recommendations